# How to make a parent movieclip listen to a customevent, dispatched by a child of child movieclip ?

Tags: actionscript-3

There are 3 Movieclips on stage

A => B => C  ( B is the child of A,  C is the child of B )

When i use a builtin event like MouseEvent.CLICK, on movieclip "C", then   it automatically propogates to movieclip "A". I don't need any type of "dispatch" function at any level. This is understandable, since events propogate from child to parent automatically.

But when i use a customevent say "onMyCustomEvent", and use dispatch function inside "C". I cannot get it propogated ? How can i make the propgation of a customevent, same as how it happens for a built-in event ?

Answer (score 0):

When you register event handler set third parameter `useCapture` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are calling propagation is actually called "bubbling".

An Event bubbles up the display list.
This is also the reason why one should `addEventListener()` for `KeyboardEvent` and `MouseEvent` at the `stage` in order to capture them regardless of focus:

From wherever the `Event` starts bubbling up, it will always end up at the `stage`, which is the top most object in the display list hierarchy.

In order to create a bubbling `Event`, pass `true` as the second parameter to the constructor of the `Event` class:

see here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#Event%28%29

```
public function Event(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
```

> bubbles:Boolean (default = false) — Determines whether the Event object participates in the bubbling stage of the event flow. The default value is false.

You do this when calling `super()` in your `CustomEvent`'s constructor, e.g.:

```
super("whatever", true);
```